# Installing EXE with Configuration File via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I was having trouble trying to install an EXE with a configuration file argument.  It seems that my location for the INI is causing it to fail but I cannot figure out how to specify the $scriptdirectory in the arguments without it failing.

```
$CurrentLocation = "$scriptdirectory\Files\"
    $exe = "ngsetup64_en.exe"
    $ini = "$CurrentLocation\ngsetup.ini"
    $Arguments = "-silent", "-f=$ini"

    Start-Process -FilePath "$CurrentLocation\$exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

Comment: Is $scriptdirectory defined somewhere else or are you trying to get the PS Automated variable $PSScriptRoot?

Comment: Automated Variable, it works fine for the exe path, but the argument is where it has problems.  I can manually specify the c:\.... path and it works fine for the argument but as soon as I put the script location it comes up as cant find the file and fails.

Comment: What is the error you actually get?  Are there spaces in $ini?  What are the values of your variables before you call Start-Process?  Beyond that, I usually prefer using Join-Path to string concatenation for file paths.  It tends to work much more smoothly.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am getting the file cannot be found error because its not allowing me to do -f= then the $scriptdirectory, it does allow me to do -f=c:\... though

Comment: is $scriptdirectory populated with anything?  It isn't a default automated variable, you want $PSScriptRoot for that.  If it is populating you have multiple backslashes but that typically shouldn't be an issue.  Could try removing the redundant backslash in your $ini variable.

Comment: I did catch that redundant backslash and actually removed it after posting with no luck.  And $scriptdirectory is populating properly like i said before I can install the exe alone just fine, its when I go to add the arguments and it fails saying cannot find file.  But the files are in the same folder so have no idea why it works for the EXE and not the INI